# Looking for guidance with classes

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm currently working on a project where I was asked to make a program for a small business (in this case a small movie theater) where I can record and print receipts for various products and customers.

What I have so far is a series of codes that record what the customer wants to order.

How do I go about making another class that stores and calculate the prices and print out to the console what the receipt might look like?

I'm not asking for the answer, just some guidance.

```
namespace RecieptApp
{
    class Reciept
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            double DoubleDiscount;
            int IntFoodOrdered;
            int IntDrinkOrdered;
            double DoubleFoodSize;
            double DoubleDrinkSize;
            int ACustomer;
            int BCustomer;
            string CustomerDescription;
            string FoodDescription;
            string DrinkDescription;

            Console.Write("How many adults: ");
            ACustomer = Console.Read();
            Console.Write("How many kids: ");
            BCustomer = Console.Read();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Are you a government employee, current or retired military, or classified disabled? (Please answer yes or no) :");
                string input1 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (input1 == "yes")
                {
                    DoubleDiscount = .15;
                    CustomerDescription = "Special Discount";
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to order some popcorn?");
                string FoodInput1 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (FoodInput1 == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many would you like?");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out IntFoodOrdered);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("And would you like that in small or large?");
                        string FoodInput2 = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (FoodInput2 == "small")
                        {
                            DoubleFoodSize = 3.75;
                            FoodDescription = "S";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DoubleFoodSize = 6.75;
                            FoodDescription = "L";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Would you like to order a drink?");
                string DrinkInput1 = Console.ReadLine();
                if (DrinkInput1 == "yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("How many would you like?");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out IntDrinkOrdered);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("And Would you like that in small or large?");
                        string DrinkInput2 = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (DrinkInput2 == "small")
                        {
                            DoubleDrinkSize = 2.75;
                            DrinkDescription = "S";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DoubleDrinkSize = 5.75;
                            DrinkDescription = "L";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            //This is where the other class would go in
            //I just dont know how to go about it so that it would minimized the amount of code I have //to write

            RecieptList Items = new RecieptList();

            Items.AddProduct(ACustomer);
            Items.AddProduct(BCustomer);
            Items.AddProduct(CustomerDescription);
            Items.AddProduct(FoodDescription);
            Items.AddProduct(DrinkDescription);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ('i' before 'e', except after 'c'.) At the least, you need to add a 'price' variable that gets added to with each purchase.  That doesn't _need_ to be in another class

Comment: . You may check out [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/0b802bd6-25ea-4a1f-8cb1-a1fabbb05356) for some ideas. If you can get a hold of [Headfirstc#](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfcsharp/) that gives beautiful guide on classes, objects, methods. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to make a class, you'll probably want to make a class that will represent a generic product, and then have a method to get a detail line from that product

since I have nothing better to do, I've made you a SSCCE.  It's overly simplified, but it it meets your requirement for a very specific case, and it uses an object.

I'm sure you're smart enough to use some of the concepts to meet your specific needs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

    public class Product
    {
        public string description;
        public double price;
        //normally you want to use eitehr an int for price(representing cents) or a decimal type, instead of double
        //just using a double here for the sack of simplicity
        // you'll also want to use properties instead of variable fields, but i'm using variable fields for simplicity

        // constructor
        public Product(string description, double price)
        {
            this.description = description;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public string GetDetailLine()
        {
            // google "String.Format" for more information,
            // basically it replaces things in the {0} and {1}, with the other parameters
            // the ":c" in {1:c} part means format as currency
            return String.Format("You ordered {0}.  It costs: {1:c}", description, price);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();


            Console.Write("Do You Want a Soda?   ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            //the .ToUpper() part makes it upper case
            if (input.ToUpper() == "YES")
            {
                Product soda = new Product("soda", 2.50);
                products.Add(soda);
            }

            double total = 0; 
            for(int i = 0; i<products.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(products[i].GetDetailLine());
                total += products[i].price;
            }

            //you can also use Console.Writeline like String.Format
            Console.WriteLine("Your Total is:  {0:c}", total);


            // this is just to pause in-case you're debugging from visual studio
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new with C# but for this model if I want to use more than one product how can I add it to the List?

Comment: @NghiaLe  just use the `products.Add()` method again

Comment: I tried doing 
                Console.Write("How many adults? ");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out AdultTicket);
            Product adultTicket = new Product("Adult Tickets", 7.75);
            products.Add(AdultTicket);

To but it wont let me continue when I debug it.

Comment: @NghiaLe  First, Code is better suited for your question, and not comments.  Secondly,  `adultTicket` is not capitalized when you declare it, but it is when you use it.

Comment: I appreciate your patient Sam, but in the log it says "Argument1: cannot convert from "int" to "ConsoleApplication2.Product". I declared AdultTicket as int to keep count of how many tickets ordered.

And Im asking because I would like to do that with all the products.

Comment: @NghiaLe you can add a `count` property to `Product`